# application pool vs application domain vs worker process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Can anyone clarify whether the below assumptions are correct?

1. One web-server can have multiple application pool
2. One application pool can have multiple application domain.
3. Each   Application  domain maps to one worker process. (not in web garden)
4. One worker process can maps to multiple application domain.
5. Each worker process, can have multiple threads per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One web-server can have multiple application pool ***(Correct)***
2. One application pool can have multiple application domain. ***(Correct)***
3. Each Application domain maps to one worker process. (not in web garden)
4. One worker process can maps to multiple application domain.
   ***(3 & 4 - not in web garden, every App Domin inside an App Pool shares same worker process.)***
5. Each worker process, can have multiple threads per request. ***(Correct)***

Comment: In an article it menioned application pool with multiple worker process is called web garden. is it correct?

Comment: Correct. Multiple worker processes assigned to a single app pool is called Web Garden.

Comment: 2 is incorrect. AppDomain is a concept within a worker process. So that point is meaningless.